# ObjectAnimator on Drawable object

Tags: android, android-drawable, objectanimator

I want to use an `ObjectAnimator` on a `Drawable` (not a `View`).
Let's say that I have an `ImageView` and with a `Drawable` as source:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@color/myColor"
    android:src="@drawable/myDrawable/>
```

What I want is that only `myDrawable` is animated and not for example the background set on the `ImageView`.

Now if I apply an `ObjectAnimator` on the drawable nothing happens:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable myDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myDrawable, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.start();
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried AnimationDrawable?

Comment: You should apply that to the imageView, use another view as background if you need it.

Comment: @Ricardo `AnimationDrawable` is not an `ObjectAnimator` and force you to have multiple `Drawable` as animation frames.

Comment: @Nanoc this is not what I want. I want it to work for example also on compound drawables of `Button` and `TextView`

Comment: Try Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable);

Comment: You can do it on any view like a button or textview, if you want just the image to animate but not the whole control then this is not the correct approach

Comment: replace `ofFloat` with `ofInt` and change the `int... values`

Comment: OFfloat is correct for alpha animation

Comment: @pskink using int (Drawable has alpha set by int and not by float @Ricardo) I'm able to animate the alpha. And if I want to rotate the drawable?

Comment: then use `RotateDrawable`

Comment: @Nanoc if he wants just the image to animate but not the whole control then this **is the correct** approach

Comment: @pskink thats only if its possible to animate the drawable alone, i was thinking it isnt.

Comment: @Nanoc `"i was thinking it isnt."` what you mean? he wants to fade out only the image drawable and wants the background to be unchanged

Comment: @pskink and using `RotateDrawable` which is the correct property? "rotate"? "rotation"? I have to do this right? `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rPhone, "rotate", 0, 360)`

Comment: no, no "rotate", docs say: `A Drawable that can rotate another Drawable based on the current level value. The start and end angles of rotation can be controlled to map any circular arc to the level values range.

It can be defined in an XML file with the <rotate> element. ` so it rotates another drawable based on the **level** value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink comments I figured out what was the problem:
`Drawable` has the alpha property as an `int` and not `float`.

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myDrawable, "alpha", 255, 0);
```